# Jenkins - custom job properties?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to add some new job properties to my job and show the values of those properties in the Jenkins list view.  I googled and went over the Jenkins plugins list, but couldn't find any hints. Is there a plugin can do this? Thanks!

Comment: It depends what you mean by "job properties" and "list view". If you mean the dashboard, where all the jobs are listed, you could potentially manage this by installing the Extra Columns plugin, and setting your info in the job description.

Comment: @Christopher , I think you should add this as an answer.

Comment: Hi Christopher, Yes. By "list view" I mean the dashboard.  I've taken your approach to put the extra information in the job description, not perfect, but works.  If you could add this as an answer, I could accept it so you will get the credits. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "job properties" and "list view".

If you mean the dashboard, where all the jobs are listed, you could potentially manage this by installing the Extra Columns plugin, and setting your info in the job description.